# Vue - Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying to set a url parameter before making an api call to my wordpress backend but i'm getting **Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"**. What am I doing wrong?

SearchPage.Vue

```
export default {
    props: {
        page: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            postsRequest: {
                type: 'posts',
                params: {
                    per_page: this.$store.state.site.posts_per_page,
                    page: this.page,
                    search: null
                },
                showLoading: true
            },
            totalPages: 0,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        getTerm() {
            return this.$route.query.search
        },
        posts() {
            if (this.getTerm) {
                return this.$store.getters.requestedItems(this.postsRequest)
            }
        },
        title() {
            return this.getTerm ? this.getTerm : ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getPosts() {
            return this.$store.dispatch('getItems', this.postsRequest)
        },
        setPostsRequestParams() {
            this.postsRequest.params.search = this.getTerm
        },
        setTotalPages() {
            this.totalPages = this.$store.getters.totalPages(this.postsRequest)
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.setPostsRequestParams().then(() => this.getPosts()).then(() => this.setTotalPages())
    }
}
</script>
```

`this.setPostsRequestParams().then(() => this.getPosts()).then(() => this.setTotalPages())` is giving me the error.

Basically i want to be able to get the parameter value from the url (*`getTerm()`*), set it in `postsRequest.params.search` in the data before make the api call and then run the `getPosts()`.

Apologies if its a silly mistake, still learning.

Comment: `setPostsRequestParams` isn't returning anything, so it implicitly returns `undefined`. You need a promise to call `then` but there is no promise here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `created()` method like the following to eliminate your TypeError:

```
created() {
    this.setPostsRequestParams();
    this.getPosts().then(
        () => this.setTotalPages();
    );
}
```

The only method that returns a promise in your code is `this.getPosts()` therefore, it is the only method that will contain the `then()` function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're expecting that method to return a promise. Currently, it's not returning anything. If it's desired that the `.then` acting on `this.setPostsRequestParams()`, then `setPostsRequestParams` needs to return something along the lines of `IPromise<[desired return type]>`.

Answer (score 1):

`.then()` returns a Promise. None of the methods you're invoking return a Promise.

Suffice to say, since there's no async required for what you're trying to do, you can simply execute in that order:

```
created() {
  this.setPostsRequestParams()
  this.getPosts()
  this.setTotalPages()
}
```

If you wanted to use `.then()` you'll want your methods to return Promises that resolve, even though I cannot see what meaningful resolve they would return but here are what the Promise would look like:

```
methods: {
  getPosts() {
    return this.$store.dispatch('getItems', this.postsRequest)
  },
  setPostsRequestParams() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.postsRequest.params.search = this.getTerm
      resolve(true)
    })

  },
  setTotalPages() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.totalPages = this.$store.getters.totalPages(this.postsRequest)
      resolve(true)
    })
  }
},

created() {
  this.setPostsRequestParams()
    .then(() => this.getPosts())
    .then(() => this.setTotalPages())
}
```

Comment: `this.$store.dispatch(...)` will return a promise, so most likely you would want to return that rather than creating a new promise.

Comment: @skirtle Well spotted! Thanks

Comment: One clarification to the first sentence might be to state that `.then` doesn't specifically return a promise; it returns whatever is provided within the `.then`. It doesn't have to return anything, and if it does return something, it's not forced to be a promise. Chaining promises would be the case the `.then` returns another promise.

Comment: @HoratiusCocles In theory, yes, if you are referring to parameters as return values. However, `.then()` itself will always return a promise in composition.

Comment: @Cue Correct. I apologize for my misunderstanding of how .then's work in composition.